# Как преобразовать datetime.time в datetime.datetime?

Tags: python

Имеются объекты класса `datetime.time`, как можно ими манипулировать между собой?

Например, `(datetime.time - datetime.time)` не работает. Чего не скажешь про класс `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: Не надо так... Надеюсь.

Comment: А как нужно сделать?

Comment: связанный вопрос [python time + timedelta equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/656297/4279)